# What is a Dedicated IP?

Tags: ip, domain-name

I am trying to purchase a domain name that I want and the person says that it's expensive because it comes with a IP address.  I have never heard of this.  What exactly is a dedicated IP?  What are they good for?  What would be a reasonable price for a domain and a dedicated IP?

Comment: Google didn't work for you? https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=dedicated+ip&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=6fefa4228f039aac&biw=1280&bih=630

Comment: @Kyle We're supposed to be source for Google.

Comment: I did Google and the only references I found were from several years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dedicated IP is static IP that is routable, and it used on the Internet to find your services, like a web site. Your DNS entry will point to that static IP. Often the term dedicated is associated with a service like Amazon's server instances, or your web hosting company giving you a dedicated IP address rather than sharing one for multiple web sites.

Comment: I just want the Domain, but this guys says that I would need to pay for the IP as well.

Comment: If you host it at Godaddy, or 1 & 1 Internet, you will not need to buy a dedicated IP. Based on the nature of this question and your responses, I doubt that it is a huge site, so let them do it. It is cheap, reliable, and you don't need your own IP. Also, it sounds like they may be trying to oversell you, but I obviously can't be sure.

Comment: @CaseyB indeed, buying domains does not require you pay for a hosting service (which would be what the IP is for). Godaddy is who I tend to use, they push a lot of extras, but you're not required to pay for any of it. I actually recommend you try registering through Google Apps.

Comment: +1 after my edit (see edit comment for details)